# Parameters for filter function

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS, how can I pass parameters to a custom filter function? In this case, I need both `task` and `status` to be available in the filter function.

But Angular only injects `task`. How can I add `status`?

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="status in statuses">
    Selected Status: {{ status.title }
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="task in tasks | filter:customFilter">
            Task Status: {{ task.status }
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.customFilter = function( task, status ) 
{
    // use task and status to show only those tasks that have the selected status
};
```

I have tried `<li ng-repeat="task in tasks | filter:customFilter( task, status )">` but that did not work.

Comment: Side note: I think `Status = {{ status.title }` should be `Status = {{ status.title }}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass multiple parameters into a filter, you just need to separate them by colons.  In the case of using a filter function, you just need to wrap the existing filter function in a custom filter.

```
app.filter('customFilterName', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    var standardFilter = $filter('filter');
    return function (tasks, status) {
        return standardFilter(tasks, function (task) {
            // use task and status to show only those tasks that have the selected status
        });
    };
}]);
```

The first line is the definition for the filter factory function.  The second line loads the standard filter filter (stupid naming I know).  The third line is the definition of the actual filter function we have created and in the 4th line we wrap the existing filter to handle our input.

It's a little complicated on the surface, but it makes things much more readable in the view to use custom named filters and parameters and it gets rid of a lot of the boiler plate that comes along with specifying an object as the parameter.

And in your view:

```
<div ng-repeat="status in statuses">
    Status = {{ status.title }
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="task in tasks | customFilterName:status">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this. Put a console.log into the function. Nver gets called.

Comment: that was my typo, so change widgets to tasks and that error goes away

Comment: Well, your code works now. However, I just noticed that my code `// use task and status to show only those tasks that have the selected status` uses variables that are within the $scope of the controller that I originally had my filter in. So having it in the app is useless for me. Is there any way I can make this filter work in the controller?

Comment: The filter doesn't need the scope, the scope is available in the view which you use to call the filter.  Can you update the question with the now not working code so I can see what's happening?

Comment: What I mean is this: Originally, I had my `customFilter` function inside a `MyCtrl` controller. Inside my `customFilter` function, I made use of variables that are part of `MyCtrl`'s `$scope`. But since I have now added your new filter function to the app, not the controller, I obviously have no access to the `$scope` of `MyCtrl` anymore.

Comment: The workaround here is to add the variables that I want as parameters to the filter since, as you said, the scope is available in the view. However, I'd much rather have my filter be part of the controller, instead of the app, if for nothing else than at least for modularity.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
I originally said - 
You don't have to necessarily wrap your function with $filter - it should work as-is.  To get the outer scope, use `$parent`. - This is incorrect. The parent scope should be accessible within the second ng-repeat.  ALSO, To pass multiple params, angular's native `filter` should be invoked, as the previous answer also stated.:

```
app.filter('realFilter', function(){
   return function(itemArray, param){
   var filteredList=[];
   console.log(param);
   for (var i in itemArray){
       if (itemArray[i].statum == param){
           filteredList.push(itemArray[i]);
       }
   }
   return filteredList;
   }
})
```

HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="task in tasks | realFilter:status.status">
    Task Status: {{ task.statum }}
</li>
```

[Here's the plunk](http://plunker.co/edit/nbdTXGLv4gXZUPM5MDHK?p=preview).

Comment: Well, your plunker logs "undefined". Am I missing the point here?

Comment: The updated plunk returns the filtered array.  To see how the filter in the controller works (without injecting $filter), use the `filter:customFilter` in the ng-repeat.  You'll see the input element in the console along with the undefined param.